# Different symbols in $...$ and align environments

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, align, inline

Is there a way to force LaTeX to produce different symbols either in `$...$` or `\begin{align}...\end{align}` environments? For example

```
$ \mymacro $
```

should lead to

> A

while

```
\begin{align} \mymacro \end{align}
```

should produce

> B ............................................................ (1)

(without the dots).

Comment: Could you explain the wider context here? This seems like a very strange request at first sight.

Comment: For example: decide when to use `\nicefrac` (`$$`) or `\frac` (align), or when to use subscripts and superscripts like `\limits` does it or when to use less space (`$$`) or more space (align) in general.

Comment: Manuals of style usually don't recommend `\nicefrac` in mathematical papers. You don't have to think to `align`, in general, but to "display" and "text" math styles, as Joseph suggested. Why don't you give some examples? Edit your question to include them.

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\mymacro{\ifinalign@ B\else A\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$ \mymacro $
\begin{align} \mymacro \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds as if you want to detect not a particular environment but the current math style. The `\mathchoice` primitive is appropriate here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\mymacro}{\mathchoice{A}{B}{C}{D}}

\begin{document}

$ \mymacro_{\mymacro} $
\begin{align} \mymacro \end{align}

\[ \mymacro \]

\end{document}
```

The four cases are display style, text style, subscript style and subsubscript style. For the demo, they are all entirely different but in a real case would be in some way related!